# Merging/Compressing list of arbitrary integer

Tags: algorithm, list, merge, compression

I'm looking for an algorithm to merge/compress lists of unsorted integers in to a single list while maintaining the original lists.

Example

```
A = [1, 1, 3]  
B = [3, 2, 9]  
C = [1, 3, 2]  
D = [1]

        A C  
        | |  
Result[ 1 1 3 2 9 ]  
        |   |  
        D   B
```

I found lots of results with similar questions but most of them deal with sorted lists or break them up. I'm sure something like this exists but I simply don't know the correct terminology.

Comment: Shortest superstring problem

Comment: @גלעדברקן Thank you that would be it! Mind posting that as an answer?